# NSMutableAttributedStrring's underline is clipping some characters from bottom

Tags: objective-c, ios9, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm using following code to underline text.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *unserlineText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"yyyy JJJJ gggggg"];
[unserlineText addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                      value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]
                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [unserlineText length])];
```

But the resulting string's underline is clipped from bottom by characters like 'y' and 'g'. You can see the results here.

[image]

Can we add some vertical space between text and underline.

Comment: This is typically how underlines look in English. It would be unusual if the underline were any lower. Descenders should penetrate it.